# how to check what is in swap?

Tags: linux, swap

On my system i have some amount of swap used:

```
undefine@uml:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16109684   15848264     261420     633496      48668    6096984
-/+ buffers/cache:    9702612    6407072
Swap:     15622140        604   15621536
```

How to check what is in swap?

I try to check it via processes, but for every pid on system VmSwap is 0:

```
undefine@uml:~$ awk '/VmSwap/ {print $2}' /proc/*/status |uniq
0
```

What else can be in swap?
I thought about tmpfs - but i reread all files on tmpfs-es - and it doesn't flush swap size.

---

Answer (score 12):

`smem` is the standard tool for this. It's clean and simple.

On a Debian based system, install it via  package manager:

```
 sudo apt-get install smem
```

A sample (clipped) output from my system:

```
$ smem -s swap -t -k -n
  PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS 
  831 1000     /bin/bash                          0     3.8M     3.8M     5.5M 
 3931 1000     bash /usr/bin/sage -c noteb   276.0K     4.0K    20.0K     1.2M 
17201 1000     /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit   284.0K     4.0K     8.0K   500.0K 
17282 1000     /usr/bin/mate-settings-daem   372.0K    11.0M    11.7M    21.8M 
17284 1000     marco                         432.0K    16.7M    18.1M    29.5M 
17053 1000     mate-session                  952.0K     3.3M     3.5M     9.2M 
 3972 1000     python /usr/lib/sagemath/sr     2.7M   101.8M   102.1M   104.3M 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  141 1                                        5.2M     3.9G     4.0G     4.5G
```

Comment: But does it return anything other than the value shown in the `VmSwap` line in `/proc/PID/status`? The question isn't asking for a prettier display, it's asking what could be in swap other than process data.

Comment: smem doesn't give me nothing more usefull than greping proc:

    undefine@uml:~$ sudo smem -c swap |uniq -c
          1     Swap 
        227        0

Answer (score 5):

I only started looking into it yesterday for my needs, below is what I've found so far:

*SWAP_USED = Used_by_Processes + SwapCached + Part_of_Tmpfs + something_else*

### Short story:

*Used_by_Processes* – data that has been swapped out from memory completely.

*SwapCached* – data that has been swapped to disk, but still remains in memory.

*Part_of_Tmpfs* – some portion of tmpfs data.

### Long story:

*Used_by_Processes* – there are many instructions published on how to **mis**-calculate this one ;) E.g. if we sum up all `VmSwap` entries from `/proc/*/status` or `Swap` entries from `/proc/*/smaps` - we will get an overestimate (shared swapped pages could get counted more than once). If we don't run it from `root` user or our OS - the underestimate will be silently returned. I don't have a proper way of identifying shared pages, but splashing of same 'maps' gives much better **approximation** than other approaches: (note that `cat` below is not useless and actually needs a `2>/dev/null`)

```
[root@a:~]# cat /proc/*/status|awk '      /^VmSwap/{           s+=$2       }END{print s}'
32048
[root@a:~]# cat /proc/*/smaps|awk '         /^Swap/{           s+=$2       }END{print s}'
32048
[root@a:~]# cat /proc/*/smaps|awk '/-/{r=$0}/^Swap/{if(R[r]!=1)s+=$2;R[r]=1}END{print s}'
14940
[root@a:~]# free -k|grep -e Swap -e used
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Swap:      8388600      15508    8373092
```

*SwapCached* – this one is straightforward and can be cleanly extracted from `/proc/meminfo`. Some people wouldn't expect this to be counted as "used" swap, since a duplicate (non-dirty) copy of same page in both RAM and Swap can be freed on either side quite instantly (in case if demand comes) thus making one of the copies "freed".

*Part_of_Tmpfs* – the bright side is that when all Your tmpfs data is many-days-untouched and `swappiness` is non-zero - it's quite likely that entire tmpfs is swapped-out (and vice-versa for recently-used data). The downside is I've found no API to reliably calculate the threshold or percentage of how much of it IS swapped, though if there's enough RAM - we can copy entire tmpfs data into `/dev/null` and thus get some clue of how much of it WAS swapped.

Common mistakes made during calculation of tmpfs size are - assuming that `/dev/shm` is the only tmpfs configured or trying to do it by recursive per-file scanning (not only implementations tend to omit hidden files or do it from non-`root`, but it also un-swaps some pages during traversing). Much easier way is to use good old `df`.

*something_else* – see the "`diff 385 MB`" below, needs a dive into kernel sources. See my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPFS=`df -kP           |awk '          /^tmpfs/{          s+=$3       }END{print int( s/1024)}'`
PROCS=`cat /proc/*/smaps|awk '/-/{r=$0} /^Swap/{if(R[r]!=1)s+=$2;R[r]=1}END{print int( s/1024)}'`
SCACH=`cat /proc/meminfo|awk '          /^SwapCached/                      {print int($2/1024)}'`
TOTAL=`free -k          |awk '          /^Swap/                            {print int($3/1024)}'`
echo  -e " df $TMPFS\t    smaps $PROCS \tSwapCache $SCACH\t| $TOTAL\tswap | diff $[TOTAL-TMPFS-PROCS-SCACH]\tMB"
```

and the output from different boxes:

```
xa002:   df 0       smaps 271   SwapCache 3858  | 4120  swap | diff -9  MB
sg003:   df 0       smaps 234   SwapCache 3876  | 4111  swap | diff 1   MB
sg001:   df 0       smaps 245   SwapCache 3845  | 4093  swap | diff 3   MB
sg002:   df 0       smaps 244   SwapCache 3843  | 4091  swap | diff 4   MB
dm001:   df 2       smaps 971   SwapCache 728   | 1707  swap | diff 6   MB
hm012:   df 270     smaps 161   SwapCache 29    | 454   swap | diff -6  MB
hm003:   df 274     smaps 142   SwapCache 27    | 440   swap | diff -3  MB
hm006:   df 262     smaps 150   SwapCache 29    | 437   swap | diff -4  MB
hm002:   df 265     smaps 120   SwapCache 28    | 412   swap | diff -1  MB
hm009:   df 258     smaps 124   SwapCache 33    | 410   swap | diff -5  MB
hm011:   df 262     smaps 118   SwapCache 28    | 406   swap | diff -2  MB
hm008:   df 245     smaps 122   SwapCache 32    | 396   swap | diff -3  MB
hm005:   df 247     smaps 120   SwapCache 33    | 396   swap | diff -4  MB
dp001:   df 0       smaps 0     SwapCache 0     | 386   swap | diff 386 MB
hm014:   df 184     smaps 134   SwapCache 34    | 343   swap | diff -9  MB
hm007:   df 0       smaps 132   SwapCache 32    | 158   swap | diff -6  MB
bm002:   df 0       smaps 121   SwapCache 25    | 141   swap | diff -5  MB
dm002:   df 2       smaps 70    SwapCache 71    | 139   swap | diff -4  MB
bm001:   df 3       smaps 102   SwapCache 28    | 131   swap | diff -2  MB
bm004:   df 0       smaps 98    SwapCache 29    | 126   swap | diff -1  MB
hm013:   df 0       smaps 100   SwapCache 30    | 124   swap | diff -6  MB
bm006:   df 0       smaps 103   SwapCache 15    | 122   swap | diff 4   MB
hm010:   df 0       smaps 102   SwapCache 24    | 122   swap | diff -4  MB
hm001:   df 0       smaps 101   SwapCache 25    | 121   swap | diff -5  MB
bm003:   df 0       smaps 98    SwapCache 15    | 107   swap | diff -6  MB
bm005:   df 0       smaps 70    SwapCache 17    | 85    swap | diff -2  MB
sg004:   df 0       smaps 72    SwapCache 14    | 83    swap | diff -3  MB
sg001:   df 0       smaps 41    SwapCache 33    | 78    swap | diff 4   MB
sg005:   df 0       smaps 59    SwapCache 20    | 75    swap | diff -4  MB
sg003:   df 0       smaps 58    SwapCache 18    | 72    swap | diff -4  MB
sg006:   df 0       smaps 56    SwapCache 13    | 65    swap | diff -4  MB
sg002:   df 0       smaps 54    SwapCache 12    | 64    swap | diff -2  MB
xa001:   df 0       smaps 56    SwapCache 5     | 55    swap | diff -6  MB
```

And a small experiment as the bonus:

```
[root@hm012:~]# df -h|grep -e '^Filesystem' -e '^tmpfs'
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  12G  271M   12G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 8.0G   84K  8.0G   1% /tmp
[root@hm012:~]# ./get_swap.sh
 df 270     smaps 161   SwapCache 29    | 454   swap | diff -6  MB
[root@hm012:~]# rm -rf /dev/shm/*
[root@hm012:~]# df -h|grep -e '^Filesystem' -e '^tmpfs'
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 8.0G   84K  8.0G   1% /tmp
[root@hm012:~]# ./get_swap.sh
 df 0       smaps 161   SwapCache 29    | 185   swap | diff -5  MB
```

P.S. aside from the approximation mentioned above - there are other sources of error, like rounding of KB into MB, theoretical possibility of a mismatch between block-sizes of RAM and Swap, etc. I'm not sure it covers everything, but hoping this helps to some extent :)